# A quantum algorithm with high probability on a 4 to 1 function

Tags: quantum-computing

Let `f : {0, 1}ⁿ → {0, 1}ⁿ` be a 4-to-1 function, such that there exist
distinct and non-zero `a, b ∈ {0, 1}ⁿ` such that for all `x ∈ {0, 1}ⁿ:`
`f(x) = f(x ⊕ a) = f(x ⊕ b) = f(x ⊕ a ⊕ b)`.
Note that ⊕ is a bit-wise xor, and that for all `y ∉ {x, x ⊕ a, x ⊕ b, x ⊕ a ⊕ b}, f(y) ≠ f(x)`. Find
a quantum algorithm that with high probability reports the set `{a, b, a ⊕ b}`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, choosing `x` to be 0 gives `f(0) = f(a) = f(b) = f(a xor b)`. And there are no other inputs that match `f(0)`. So we're just looking for `v` satisfying `v != 0, f(v) = f(0)`. So make a circuit that takes a `v` and inverts phase when it satisfies else does nothing otherwise. Then apply grover's algorithm. The running time would be `O(sqrt(N))` to find the first value. Then you repeat with it conditioned out as well.

On the other hand, just classically sampling at random until you find a collision also has expected time `O(sqrt(N))` so there's probably something even more clever you can do.